Difference between てしまう and つい〜てしまう
Is there any difference in nuance to the てしまう construction when つい precedes it?
In the following sentence:

とってもキレイなネックレス
あんまりステキだったから
つい拾っちゃった

Would the nuance change if つい was omitted?

#3 https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84

As a heads up, you will come across these types of structures in Japanese all of the time. つい～ちゃった(てしまった) are parts of common Japanese sentence structure, where both つい and ちゃう convey the same nuance in English, that is, "accidentally~, ended up~, unintentionally~". Really the only difference by adding つい (in this case) is that it really reinforces that nuance of "ended up~, unintentionally~". You will see similar structures like, "どうやら~よう/そう/らしい/etc." where both words (or grammar constructs) at the beginning and end of a given clause convey the same meaning.
